# Newbie advice on possibility to parallelize using GPU

Tags: r, parallel-processing, gpu

I am trying to learn how to parallelize using GPUs. I have a specific problem: a particle filter which I would like to parallelize. The thing is that I have been reading around and I really do not understand if a) it is possible and b) where to start to program it in case it is possible. Here is a minimal code in R that would help to understand my problem:

```
library(NPflow)

N   = 1000
mup = c(0.5,0,0.3)
S   = matrix(c(1,0,0,0.5,1,0,-0.7,0.3,1),3,3,byrow=T)
X   = mup + S%*%rnorm(3)
C   = S%*%t(S)
mupr = matrix(rnorm(3*N),3)
Cr  = lapply(rep(4,N),wishrnd,Sigma=C)
llk = mmvnpdfC(X, mean=mupr, varcovM=Cr, Log = TRUE)
```

The last line of the code computes a multivariate normal pdf for a vector X [3x1] given 1000 possible means and 1000 possible covariance matrices. Using the package NPflow I can use the function mmvnpdfC which works similar to mvnpdf in Matlab. Indeed, it is similar as doing this for loop:

```
llkfor = NULL

for (n in 1:N){

    llkfor[n] = mvnpdf(X,mupr[,n],Cr[n])

}
```

Of course, this simple code runs quite fast, but my model is gonna be significantly larger and the question would be if I can parallelize the previous 'for-loop' using GPU. In my application, I will require N to be at least 50,000. Of course, I can parallelise with the CPU, but I have access only to 4 cores, so I was planning to invest in a good NVIDIA card if it could help me.

Any advice/recommendation/reading material would be very useful.

Thank you all in advance!!